# Voting to close

Tags: support, bug

I flagged a post to be moved to another Stack Exchange site.

When I choose, 
"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" the only choice I have is "Homebrewing Meta", which doesn't make sense...  is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Per [this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85041/245727), it looks like only a moderator can move questions to sites not explicitly listed on that screen.  I vaguely recall seeing on a previously that there's some kind of special way to get sites added to that list but I think it would need to be driven by need and relevance.  For example, I could imagine us eventually getting Beer, Wine, & Spirits added there if we were frequently migrating questions there but questions intended for Stack Overflow are presumably less common here.

Regardless, I saw your flag at effectively the same time as your post here and was able to move the question without any problems.